# Why JSONLoader does not immediately add child to the scene?

Tags: three.js

Link to webpage: http://door-in-wall.asg-3d.ru

Source: http://door-in-wall.asg-3d.ru/source.zip

After calling *init()* initializes the scene: added camera, light, generated geometry (text and  sphere), and loaded with *JSonLoader* 3D model.
Camera, light and generated geometry has be added to the scene immediately, but when *JSonLoader* loads the model - I can not understand ...

```
  // Create 3D Text Mesh
  var textMesh3 = new THREE.Mesh( text3d3, textMaterial );
  textMesh3.position.x = textMesh1.position.x;
  textMesh3.position.y = textMesh2.position.y - text3d1.boundingBox.max.y * 2.6;

  scene.add( textMesh3 );

  console.log('textMesh3 within init() = ', textMesh3); //textMesh3 = THREE.Mesh
  console.log('scene.children.length after load textMesh3 = ', scene.children.length); //scene.children.length = 6


  // Add back plane
  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader().load( "js/backplane.js", function ( geometry ) {

    geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    backPlaneMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, backPlaneMeshMaterial );
    backPlaneMesh.position.set(SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, 0);
    backPlaneMesh.scale.set(4, 4, 4);

    scene.add(backPlaneMesh);

  });

  console.log('JSONLoader within init() = ', loader); //loader = undefined 
  console.log('scene.children.length after load JSONLoader = ', scene.children.length); //scene.children.length = 6
```

I left the console output to a descendant of scene *console.log (scene.children.length)*: Line 103, 148, 167.

If you check *scene.children.length* **after** calling *animate()* and *render()*, then it will show the presence of 7 children.

How and when model is loading with JSONLoader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loader.load()` is asynchronous. In other words, it doesn't stop the code execution until is completed. It will load in parallel and will execute the callback when is done. Depending on how big the model is it may take some seconds to download and parse. Even if you're loading it locally it will take some milliseconds.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit. If you wanted everything to appear at the same time. You could utilize the callbacks in your calls to .load() in order to hold off rendering until everything has been completely loaded. One call to load can be the callback to the previous. The last callback can contain calls to init() and animate().

Comment: I use jQuery.Deferred to chain loaders - very handy tool for it

Comment: Thanks all for the clarification!